# What does "only supported on linux's native backend" mean for the call command in Delve?

Tags: go, reverse-engineering, delve

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65382076/is-setting-a-string-value-currently-supported-in-delve) is related. I have `aarch64` Alpine Linux emulated using QEMU on a `x86_64` Ubuntu 16.04 host which itself is installed in VirtualBox on a Mac. I've been trying to use the `Delve` `call` command to modify a string value. I have absolutely no idea how to do so. Nevertheless, even a simple `(dlv) call` returns:

`(dlv) call`

`> main.my_function() /usr/lib/go/src/strings/strings.go:308 (hits goroutine(50):1 total:1) (PC: 0x4a929c)`

`Warning: debugging optimized function`

`Command failed: backend does not support function calls`
In particular, `(dlv) help call` returns

`Resumes process, injecting a function call (EXPERIMENTAL!!!)`

```
call [-unsafe] <function call expression>
```

Current limitations:

- only pointers to stack-allocated objects can be passed as argument.
- only some automatic type conversions are supported.
- functions can only be called on running goroutines that are not
  executing the runtime.
- the current goroutine needs to have at least 256 bytes of free space on
  the stack.
- functions can only be called when the goroutine is stopped at a safe
  point.
- calling a function will resume execution of all goroutines.
- only supported on linux's native backend.

I think the issue may be related to the last bullet point but I don't know what exactly it is. I'll appreciate it if someone would shed some light on it.

Comment: You cannot. Sorry. Use an other debugger or tackle your problem differently.

Comment: @Volker Can you comment on GDB being capable?

Comment: no, sorry. Never used gdb on Go executables.

Comment: @Volker I've been doing that lately and its so confusing. I'm thinking the best case scenario is a version of Delve which is as handy as GDB.